# Increase notification display interval

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a notification in a PHP application which is working fine in terms of displaying the notification popup, but it isn't being displayed for long enough.

I've tried increasing the *setInterval* parameter but it doesn't seem to make a difference. The code is based on [this](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/facebook-style-popup-notification-using-php-ajax-bootstrap.html) but I can't see any guidance there on increasing the display time.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(function(){
            load_last_notification();
        }, 5000);

        function load_last_notification()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"/includes/fetch-notifications.php",
                method:"POST",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('.content').html(data);
                }
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: (Ideally I'd like the popup to remain on screen until the user clicks to close it.)

Comment: The html code for the [bootstrap alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) comes from the backend. Hence you should include the relevant backend code.